# Boost.Log: register attributes manually

Tags: c++, linker-errors, boost-log

In my code using Boost.Log I register a formatter for my log output

```
register_simple_formatter_factory<LogLevel, char>("Severity");
```

This worked as expected for some time but now I tried to build on a different platform and are getting a linker error

```
undefined reference to `void boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::register_formatter_factory<char>(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::formatter_factory<char> > const&)'
```

My guess is that this is because the installed library from the package repository was build with `BOOST_LOG_WITHOUT_DEFAULT_FACTORIES` defined. According to [the Boost.Log documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation/config.html) this means that

> the user will have to register all attributes in the library before
> parsing any filters or formatters from strings.

But how do I do this? What specifically do I have to replace my call to `register_simple_formatter_factory` with to have the same effect.

Comment: > My guess is that this is because the installed library from the package repository was build with `BOOST_LOG_WITHOUT_DEFAULT_FACTORIES` defined. -- No, this is not the reason for the linking error. Check [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html) first.

Comment: > But how do I do this? -- You don't need to replace `register_simple_formatter_factory` with anything. On the contrary, you must call `register_simple_formatter_factory` or `register_formatter_factory` for *every* attribute you use, even if you didn't have to before. Same for filters (`register_filter_factory`, `register_simple_filter_factory`). Where previously the default factories were used, you must now create and register ones manually.

Comment: @AndreySemashev Thanks for your hint about the namespace thing but I am afraid I do not fully understand. I am linking statically against Boost.Log and did not define `BOOST_LOG_NO_THREADS`. So for my understanding `v2s_mt_posix` should be correct. Using `nm` I can see that the library does in fact export symbols using this namespace. Additionally when commenting out the call to `register_simple_formatter_factory` my application builds successfully so all other symbols of Boost.Log seem to be found. What am I missing?

Comment: The question is whether you're actually linking to the static library. Most Linux distros ship shared library, and that's what linkers pick by default.

Comment: Also, make sure you're linking with `boost_log_setup`, not just `boost_log`. `boost_log_setup` should go before `boost_log` in the linker command line.

Comment: @AndreySemashev I was indeed not linking against `boost_log_setup`. After adding it my application builds successfully even with the call to `register_simple_formatter_factory`. Thank you very much for your assistance. If you post your comment as answer I will gladly accept it so that you get your reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My guess is that this is because the installed library from the package repository was build with `BOOST_LOG_WITHOUT_DEFAULT_FACTORIES` defined.

No, this is not the reason for the linking error. Disabling default factories does not remove factory registration APIs.

> But how do I do this? What specifically do I have to replace my call to `register_simple_formatter_factory` with to have the same effect.

You don't need to replace `register_simple_formatter_factory` with anything. On the contrary, you must call `register_simple_formatter_factory` or `register_formatter_factory` for every attribute you use, even if you didn't have to before. Same for filters (`register_filter_factory`, `register_simple_filter_factory`). Where previously the default factories were used, you must now create and register ones manually.

Regarding linking errors, check [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html) first. Make sure the namespace names in the library you link with match those in the linker error. If not, define configuration macros to rectify the mismatch.

Also, make sure you're linking with `boost_log_setup`, not just `boost_log`. `boost_log_setup` should go before `boost_log` in the linker command line.

Comment: I was indeed not linking against boost_log_setup. After adding it my application builds successfully even with the call to `register_simple_formatter_factory`. Thank you very much for your assistance.